# How to use windows form application button to run console files in visual studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

In my project on "Gesture Recognition" I am using Visual Studio 2010 Visual C++ and open CV there are many Win32 console application c++ files like for training, testing,creating Data-set, for HMM training,etc.For running any file I need to include that file and exclude all other files.Earlier I made it on Console application but now I want to add windows form application to this project.When I add to this project Windows Form Visual C++ and creating a button it is giving error although I have changed the properties of common language Run time support.Is there any way how I can execute these different .cpp files creating buttons on Form Application because that is using c#.

`private: System::Void Krishna_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             }
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

```
         }
};
```

}
`

Comment: Use the `Process` class to run external programs. This is quite likely a poor way to implement your program.

Comment: Your wording is confusing. Are you saying that you have implemented a GUI in C++/CLI (if not, what language?) and a console-based backend in C++, and you want to be able to run the backend from the GUI? If so, it shouldn't be hard to call the C++ code directly. Just google phrases such as "mixing unmanaged C++ with managed code". It is too broad a question for someone to post an entire tutorial as an answer. Alternatively, you could consider using a C++ (unmanaged) GUI framework so that you do not need to mix languages.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If this problem is for Visual Basic Developers, then:

Click on the button, Visual Studio will generate a code for you, which runs when user clicks the the same button in your application.

Consider the following example:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Process.Start("C:\Users\MyName\Documents\MyApp.exe")
    End Sub
End Class
```

In above mentioned code, everything except the third line, was generated automatically by Visual Studio when I clicked the button named "Button1"

When in From1, Button1 is clicked, it starts the application MyApp.exe which is inside the folder C:\Users\MyName\Documents\

This code should work in your project, as it is working for me. Using this code, you can run other files also, like .mp3 and .mp4 etc.

Comment: -1, on what basis did you assume Visual Basic? The question implies (in a badly worded way) C++/CLI.

Comment: If someone finds this answer "not useful", please mention here why?? This will give me a chance to re-frame my answer. Thank you!

Comment: I did mention why... (but see my correction to the above comment).

Comment: He has mentioned visual studio, and Windows Form Applications are created in Visual Basic language. And I faced the same problem, when I started learning Visual Basic. So, I think, it's clear that the person who asked it failed to tag it as "Visual Basic 2012 or 2010" but it is from Visual Basic

Comment: No, you have not understood correctly. Windows Forms is a .NET API and is not specific to Visual Basic (just as Visual Studio is a general purpose IDE and is not specific to Visual Basic). Just because you happened to use it in Visual Basic doesn't mean everyone does. The OP said "windows form application c++", implying that he is using C++/CLI.

Comment: Yes, you are right, WFA is not specific to Visual Basic. But look at him, he just signed up to ask this question. So I thought to help him in any possible way. I have made a little correction, in answer, if you can notice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54992/discussion-between-aniliitb10-and-jbentley).

Comment: I have replied according to what I thought. You have every right to vote down my answer. I have mentioned in my ans "if this is for VB developers". I hope he finds the answer!